# Should Unix Daemon have a main

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services

Trying to write a java Daemon for a Linux server running on AWS, As of now I have implemented the Daemon interface but i'm not sure if I should have a main function in the Daemon? or should I call the Daemon in a different way? 
What is the program entry point?

Comment: Which daemon interface?

Comment: There's a *distinct* difference between a Java daemon and a Unix daemon

Comment: Are you referring to the [Apache Commons `Daemon` interface](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/apidocs/org/apache/commons/daemon/Daemon.html)?

Comment: yes i'm referring to the Apache Commons Daemon interface, using that interface how can I execute it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have used AWS Flow framework, you need worker classes for this purpose. Take a look at their documentation on [running programs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/running.html) and [daemon tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/daemontasks.html).